# Adding android:configChanges to generated manifest

Tags: android, air, flash-builder

I'm using Flash Builder to build an AIR android app. To prevent the app being activated when lock screen is presented, I need to modify AndroidManifest.xml to include modified android:configChanges attribute in the application tag.

AIR provides manifestAdditions tag in AIR application descriptor file (*-app.xml) to accomplish this, but the compiler throws an error if I include configChanges attribute. I can manually unpack and edit the manifest, but then I have to re-sign the package, and that is a hassle (and kinda defeats the point of using an IDE).

Is there a way to automate the process of modifying the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tweak it within AIR, it is reserved. You'll need to do it the manual way.

Take a look at:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html

**Reserved Android manifest settings**

AIR sets several manifest entries in the generated Android manifest document to ensure that application and runtime features work correctly. You cannot define the following settings:

**manifest element**

You cannot set the following attributes of the manifest element:

- package
- android:versionCode
- android:versionName
- xmlns:android

**activity element**

You cannot set the following attributes for the main activity element:

- android:label
- android:icon

**application element**

You cannot set the following attributes of the application element:

- android:theme
- android:name
- android:label
- android:windowSoftInputMode
- **android:configChanges**
- android:screenOrientation
- android:launchMode

Comment: Yes, I've seen that too. I'm gonna hold out on accepting the answer in hope that someone has a handy procedure for inserting additional steps into the build process (between generating the manifest and signing the package).